# Remove responsiveness of Images from an id/class

Tags: css

I want to know how to remove the responsiveness of a images from a specific div. I am not using any framework, just a plain CSS that responsifies.

**Here's the code for all the images tags:**

```
img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

Some how i dont want these styles on a specific Div ID or Class.

How can i do that?

Comment: responsifies is my new favorite word. Get rid of the auto, and it should stop "responding"

Comment: Won't that stops for all the img tags? i want it to be only effective for specific div

Comment: Then create a rule that's more specific that overrides that rule. `.divclass img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset or remove the CSS that previously set by using the default values for the respective styles
Try this CSS:

```
#specificDiv img {
max-width : none;
 height : auto;}
```

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#keywords)

**(Update):** added the img tag... that's needed according to the question...

Comment: yup, added the img tag myself